# Database to android, with php

Tags: java, php, android, database, json

i'm trying to send values from a database to an Android app. I started from a tutorial and got here, but i'm getting: 
"error parsing data org.json.jsonexception end of input at character 0 of" 
I probably have other errors, but this is the first one i get when running the app.

edit: i can't delete this question, but it is no longer relevant. The code had mistakes which i corrected meanwhile.
The answers, while helpful, were not the solution. this is probably my fault, as the question was formulated badly.

Comment: Have you changed index.php ? Can you see an output now?

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because there is no JSON data being received to parse. Likely this is because you are trying to connect to the internet from within your `onCreate()` method. Since API 11, all I/O functions need to take place on a background thread. I suggest you look into using `AsyncTask` to connect to your server and download the information you need. [Here is a link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to the android docs for `AsyncTask`. The basic idea is simple, any I/O functions go in the `doInBackground()` method. Any updating of the UI, e.g. setting the text on a `TextView`, takes place within `onPostExecute()`. Read the documentation and try to implement it. If you're still getting errors then, we can help you fix it.

Comment: mm... both the database and the app run on the same machine. from what i understand, the JSON parser is sent this: "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/". The app is run the emulator that comes with eclipse.

Comment: It does not matter that you are connecting to a localhost. You are using a network operation which is an I/O function and must be run on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say is in index.php,

```
    } else if ($tag == 'get_data_tag'){
  // Request type is get data

    $Channel_id = $_POST['Channel_id'];
    $Temp_value = $_POST['Temp_value'];

//check for the value for the specified channel
    $value = $db->getDataByChannelId($Channel_id, $Temp_value);

//this is where the data should be sent to the app
    $response_data["success"] = 1;
    $response_data["Channel_id"] = $value["Channel_id"];
    $response_data["Temp_value"] = $value["Temp_value"];
    echo json_encode($response_data);
}
```

PHP may be returning a parse error (because of the else without an if), and then the JSON library (in your Java/Android code) can't read something like "Parse Error: " as JSON which would lead it to throw that error.

Disregard this if you just omitted the other bits of code from your question.

Comment: yes, there are two more cases, two more tags, and i didn't include those. They handle the login and registration of users, and they work. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

Just try this example in the below link and try to do it in the same manner.

http://android-am.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-login-screen-by-connecting-to.html

Comment: thanks, i'll see what i can learn from that, but i already have a working login and register sequence, which i made using another tutorial. now i'm trying to get values from another table to display in a text field in my app.